# Write chunks of list to file, add newline at end of chunk

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Having issues with this. I am finding a TON of examples on how to write lists to a file, and how to split a list up using list comprehension, numpy (not applicable here it seems) and other methods, but not what I am trying to do specifically.

one of my functions:

```
 def createdevstring():
        tree = ET.parse('regcheckdevicelist.xml')
        text = [child.text for child in tree.iter() if not child.text.strip() == '']
        devicename = ",".join(text)
        return devicename
```

What it does is parse an xml document and strip the xml. The list `text` ends up looking like this, though the list can have anywhere from 3 entries to 10,000+.

For example:
    ['devicename1', 'devicename2', 'devicename3']

My function currently takes those list entries and joins them to a `,` and are stored in stringvar `devicename`

Result:

```
devicename1,devicename2,devicename3,
```

This works fine, however, I am trying to hit an API that has a maximum device query count of 200 device names. If I query >200 devices, I only get 200 back in the xml response.

What I have been trying to get into code but can't get working is:

Option 1) Split up the list into subarrays containing 200 entries from the `tree` array, with the last array being an arbitrary number <=200. Do not need to be equally sized arrays, just that they can be a maximum of 200 in size. Then, I would need a way to draw out each subarray into a stringvar where the format is the same as it is current, a comma delimited value string, then run a `requests.request ["POST"....]` for each constructed cdv stringvar.

Option 2) Write list members to a file with `','` between each member, after 200 have been written add a newline `'\n'`. Then, for each line in the file, perform a `requests.request["POST"....]`

Any guidance on that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion.

First, here is an iterator function to split an iterable into chunks.

```
def chunker(sequence, chunk_size):
    it = iter(sequence)
    while True:
        chunk = []
        try:
            for i in range(chunk_size):
                chunk.append(next(it))
            yield chunk
        except StopIteration:
            if chunk:
                yield chunk
            return
```

Once you have this, I suggest that in place of your `createdevstring` function, you make a function that simply returns the text of all the elements, leaving the rest of the work to the caller.

```
def get_text_of_elements():
    tree = ET.parse('regcheckdevicelist.xml')
    return (child.text for child in tree.iter() if not child.text.strip() == '')
```

And here is what the caller could then do with it:

```
for text in chunker(get_text_of_elements(), 200):
    devicename = ",".join(text)
    # do whatever you want with it inside this loop
```

Actually here `get_text_of_elements` is returning the result as a generator, rather than creating the whole list at once, although if you prefer you could return a list by changing it back from my round brackets to the square brackets that you used originally -- it would still work.

A slight variant would be to put the conversion to device name also inside your function, but make that also be an iterator rather than return a value, so you then have a nice simple loop in the caller:

```
def get_devicenames(chunk_size=200):
    ET.parse('regcheckdevicelist.xml')
    for text in chunker(
            (child.text for child in tree.iter() if not child.text.strip() == ''),
            chunk_size):
        yield ",".join(text)


for devicename in get_devicenames():
    # ... do something ...
```